# How to include local stylesheets and scripts in Nuxt.js application?

Tags: nuxt.js

I am transferring a project from plain html to a Nuxt.js application. I am currently trying to move my stylesheets and client-side scripts to my application by including them in the `nuxt.config.js` file. However, I cannot get any method to put them in the Global Settings to function as I expect them to.

## Attempt 1: Using the examples in the Generated Code

My first attempt was to use the linked resource as a template. The default file conatins the following:

```
link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
```

However doing something like this:

```
link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', type: 'text/css', href: '/style.css' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', type: 'text/css', href: '/mbcsmbutv9.css'}
    ]
```

where, for the sake of simplicity, I placed both of my files in the same directory as the generated icon, did not display the stylesheet as being linked when inspecting the DOM.

## Attempt 2: using the Nuxt.js FAQ

My second attempt was to see if there was an official guide on how to do this.
According to the Nuxt.js FAQ "How to Use external resources?", the proper way to do this is:

> Include your resources in the nuxt.config.js file:
>
> ````
> export default {
>  head: {
>    script: [
>      { src: >'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js' }
>    ],
>    link: [
>      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?>family=Roboto&display=swap' }
>    ]
>  }
> }```
> ````

I used the examples given as a template, i.e. I pasted in their example for `script` and `link`, then replaced `src` and `href` links with the local path to the file, as such:

```
export default{
head: {
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: process.env.npm_package_description || '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/style.css' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/mbcsmbutv9.css'}
    ],
    script: [
      { src: '/assets/mbjsmbutv9.js' }
    ]
  }
}
```

## Expected Results

In the `<head>` section of the DOM, I should be seeing links to my stylesheets and my script. The 'icon' that was in the generated code always ends up being read, allowing me to find it in the DOM, however neither my stylesheets nor my scripts appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that simply adding them in the `link` section in Nuxt will do the trick:

```
link: [
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/css/style.css' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/css/mbcsmbutv9.css' },
      {rel:'stylesheet', href:'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'}

    ],
```